# Flutter Firebase auth facebook not working

Tags: android, facebook, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement different login options for my flutter app users, but can't make the facebook one work(google and email are ok).

I've followed the [installation guide](https://facebook.meedu.app/#/android) from the package [flutter_facebook_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth) but still getting an error when the token provided from facebook is going to be used as a credential to create the firebase user:

[image]

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter_facebook_auth/flutter_facebook_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
String usermail = "";
Future returnToken(User user) async {
   token = word + await user.getIdToken();
}
  Future<List<String>> facebookSignin() async {
    try {
      final _instance = FacebookAuth.instance;
      final result = await _instance.login(permissions: ["email"]);
      if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
        final OAuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.accessToken.token);
        final a = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential); //the error is in this line
        await _instance.getUserData().then((userData) async {
          await _auth.currentUser.updateEmail(userData["email"]);
          userMail = userData["email"];
        });
        await returnToken(a.user);
        return ["ok"];
      } else if (result.status == LoginStatus.cancelled) {
        return ["Erro!", "Login cancelado"];
      } else
        return ["Erro!", "Falha no login"];
    } catch (e) {
      return ["Erro!", e.toString()];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is you app on Facebook developer console in production or development mode? You need to add your hashkeys for both dev and prod into Facebook. If you haven't added your release keys and tried to sign in with a Facebook account not listed as a developer in Facebook or you don't actually own the app, you get this error.

Comment: I've added both the dev and debug keys. Found the problem this afternoon: one of the oauth configs was blocking the login...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was on the secret key option: [image]

I didn't add it on my app, so having this setting turned on blocked the app from generating a valid token to firebase.